# Alterar um componente através de outro componente - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, front-end, angular-8

Galera, eu tenho um componente Nav onde possui o logo da empresa e um componente Home, porém, na Home não poderia existir o logo que tenho no Nav. Quais seriam as formas de ocultas o logo quando o rota da home fosse ativada?

**Meu Nav**:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a [routerLink]="['/home']" class="brand-logo"><img src="assets/images/logo.png"></a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/quemsomos']" >Quem somos</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/solicitaremprestimo']">Solicitar empréstimo</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/emprestimosocial']">Empréstimo Social</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/faq']">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/videos']">Vídeos</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/contato']">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <a id="area-cliente" [routerLink]="['/area-do-cliente']">Área do cliente</a>
</nav>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
  <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
  <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
  <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```

HOME

```
<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 tittle">
      <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  Conteudo
</main>
```

app.component.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode validar ele através da rota, só mostre o logo caso a rota for diferente de `/home`.

Primeiro você precisa importar o router:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

depois adicione no constructor:

```
constructor(public router: Router) {}
```

E no componente so adicione o `*ngIf="router.routerState.snapshot.url !== '/home'"`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="router.routerState.snapshot.url !== '/home'">
    <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Show. Era isso que eu precisava. Obrigado !